# Google Calendar API always sending delivery system notification failure

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

earlier it was working fine and after working few days

I started getting response mail saying delivery system failure when I create event using php code

Below is the code I am using to create a calendar event

```
public function createEvent($subject = "Unknown Interview Scheduled",
    $attendeesArray = null,
    $startTime = null, $endTime = null,
    $accessToken = null, $refresh_token = null,
    $role = null, $phoneNumber = null,
    $candidateName = null, 
    $applicant_id = null){

    // reformating starttime and end time
    $startTime = (date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($startTime)));
    $endTime = (date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($endTime)));

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'client_secret_calender.json');
    $var =  new stdClass();
    $var->access_token = $accessToken;
    $var->refresh_token = $refresh_token;
    $var = json_encode($var);
    $client->setAccessToken($var);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => $subject,
        'description' => 'Interview Scheduled with <a href="https://app.quezx.com/Applicants/view/'.$applicant_id.'">'.$candidateName.'</a> for '.$role. ' position '."\n".' Candidate contact number : '.$phoneNumber ,
        'start' => array(
            'dateTime' => $startTime,
            'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',
        ),
        'end' => array(
            'dateTime' => $endTime,
            'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',
        ),
        /*'recurrence' => array(
            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
        ),*/
        'attendees' => $attendeesArray,
        "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests"=>false,
        'reminders' => array(
            'useDefault' => FALSE,
            'overrides' => array(
                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 30),
            ),
        ),
    ));
          $optionArguments = array("sendNotifications"=>true);
          $calendarId = 'primary';
          $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event,$optionArguments);
          pr($event);
}
```

Error is

> {
>       error: {
>       errors:
>       [
>         {
>            domain:"usageLimits",
>            reason: "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
>            message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
>           extendedHelp: "https://code.google.com/apis/console" 
>          }
>        ],
>        code: 403,
>        message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
>        }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

One of the suggested actions for **403: Daily Limit Exceeded** given in [**Handle API Errors**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors) is to follow the advice on [Google Calendar API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing). Aside from that, you can also try the suggested actions given below for 403: Calendar usage limits exceeded.

> - Read more on the Calendar usage limits in the [Google Apps Administrator help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en).
> - If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a Google Apps domain, consider using a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with authority delegation.
> - Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff).

Also, I find it really important and beneficial to apply the techniques given in [Performance Tips](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/performance) to improve the performance of your application.